# run multiple instance of racket program

Tags: scheme, instance, racket

Hello I made a simple racket program on windows xp sp3

I wonder how can I run many instance like notepad

Is it possible ?

I can't run 2 instance of my program at the same time.

Just like online game, I can't run multiple instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be hard (or maybe even impossible) at the moment.  Please post this question on our [mailing list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's something simple, maybe you could just run each instance of your program in a separate tab in Racket (in the menu: File -> New Tab)